# why same row is displayed 2 times?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT patient.P_ID, patient.P_NAME, patient.P_AGE, 
       patient.P_GENDER, patient.ADDRESS, patient.DOA, 
       patient.P_ID DIAGNOSE
FROM patient,presciption
WHERE patient.P_ID != presciption.P_ID
```

Comment: Maybe there are two equal datasets in your db?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you describe what you are trying to do. You now have an exclusive join, it will give some kind of cartesian product.

Comment: I want to display the name of patient which are not in the presciption table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a patient as long as it's not found in the presciption table:

```
select patient.P_ID, patient.P_NAME, patient.P_AGE, patient.P_GENDER, patient.ADDRESS, patient.DOA, patient.P_ID DIAGNOSE
from patient
where not exists (select 1 from presciption
                  where patient.P_ID = presciption.P_ID)
```

Comment: @siddharthranjan.  Don't forget to accept the answer.